# how to create docx file in google app engine with java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to create docx file in google app engine with java.I thought of using google docs,but it can only export as doc & not docx.Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest searching the web for "java docx" and similar keywords related to dynamically generating documents, etc.  The first hit on Google is [JavaDocX](http://www.javadocx.com/), which looks like it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

http://poi.apache.org/ might be your solution. You may not be able to write on disk within GAE environment, so you will have to flush out file to servlet or store in datastore as BLOB.

Check discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/ba0dc0438d465bad?pli=1

Comment: Apache POI relies on several classes not in the JRE class whitelist including java.awt.Color. A bug has been filed at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47497 and resolution is set to WONTFIX!